# Allow any value matching an item from an array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and currently, I'm aware that I can do this:

```
var display: 'block' | 'inline' | 'flex' | 'inline-flex' = 'block';
```

so that later in the code it will show an error if I try to assign any value to the variable `display` that doesn't match any of the above options.

But what if I have these options written earlier in the code in the form of an array? such as:

```
const displayOptions = ['block', 'inline', 'flex', 'inline-flex'];
var display: /* now what do I write here? */ = 'block';
```

I don't want to rewrite the options using the bitwise OR operator because then I'll have to re-update the options in both lines whenever I need to add or remove an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of const context:

```
const displayOptions = ['block', 'inline', 'flex', 'inline-flex'] as const;
type Options = typeof displayOptions[number];

let display: Options = 'block';    
let display2: Options = ''; // error
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for an `enum`.

```
enum Displays {
    Block = 'block',
    Inline = 'inline',
    Flex = 'flex',
    InlineFlex = 'inline-flex'

}

const display1: Displays = Displays.Block; // OK
const display2: Displays = 'block'; // error
const display3: Displays = 'something else'; // error
```

- [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAIglgZwA4BsCGBPBUDeAoKQqAIRQHsBjAaygF4oByAI3OoYBoCiBJEFOEMDqMB-QRy6EAYimAAPYQwBmsuRKJReY4DPmLRA4AFoV8hnjwBfCxTIgEAFygATRKkwBGAFyw36LMLwyP4IAHSklFQA3FAA9LFQAPIA0ni29k6uwZgATD5B7gH0zKxUDDHxUMAATtVk1Wl2ji5%20mADM%20a1FjAhkEMAOABYCAOZVKAjA5XEJNXXVQA)
- [Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
const displayOptions = ['block', 'inline', 'flex', 'inline-flex'] as const;

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

var display: ValueOf<typeof displayOptions> = 'block';
```